# Output an array to the console from a .txt file

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to copy the contents of a `.txt` file to an array and print it to the console.

The code requires a main method with two scanners (one to read input from the user, and the second to read the file), a method to make the array, and a method to print the array.

I have successfully managed to make an array and print it, but the output is not ideal. It is scattered and difficult to read. Can someone help me to improve my output so it reads more like a list?

Here is my code:

```
public class CutupSongCreator {
    // Creates two Scanner objects; one reads input from console, the other scans a file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); // SCANNER ONE (reads input)
        System.out.print("What is the input filename? ");
        String filename = console.next();
        File f = new File(filename);
        while (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.print("That file does not exist. Try again: ");
            filename = console.next();
            f = new File(filename);
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f); // SCANNER TWO (reads file)
        SongLine[] arr = makeArray(input);
        printArray(arr);
        // Sort by genre
        // System.out.print("What genre are you looking for: ");
        // String genretype = console.next();
        // if (genretype == input.next()) {
        //  System.out.print("You can't just make up a genre. Try again: ");
        //  genretype = console.next();
        // }
        // listLinesByGenre(arr, genretype);
    }

    // Creates an array of SongLines from a set of lines
    public static SongLine[] makeArray(Scanner reader) {
        int total = reader.nextInt();         // First int = # of lines
        SongLine[] arr = new SongLine[total]; // New array to hold the length of the file
        for(int i = 0;i < total; i++) {
            String genre = reader.next();
            int lineNumber = reader.nextInt();
            String words = reader.nextLine();
            SongLine temp = new SongLine(genre, lineNumber, words);
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
        reader.close();
        return arr;
    }

    // Prints out the elements of an array
    public static void printArray(SongLine[] songs) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(songs));
    }
}
```

My code makes use of a constructor class, which I could post if needed, but I think I just do not understand how to read or use the constructor file. Below are the current and desired output. The desired shows the genre, lineNumber, and script, and I would like to print it looking as so.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amG47.png)
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j2Np.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your post to include **current** and **expected** output.

Comment: Use a **for** loop to display your songs Array elements. If you want more formatting the use the [System.out.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) method.